# When converting mods to flacs, they are looped

Tags: music, sample, flac, old

## Explaination of my problem:

So i am maybe not straight forward sound designer but i thought of this StackExchange subsite as the most accurate place to ask my question. But what my problem is about? I am ripping mods (mods = sampled music) off old Amiga 500 disks and slightly modify those mods by enchancing quality of samples and adding few mine notes but i encounter quite big problem. After ripping data off mentioned disk i convert it to .flac file in vlc media player, beacuse i like convertion that doesnt lose any of sound. My problem is that after converting, those flacs are looped.

## What do I mean by looped?

As my main music player i use [Clementine](https://www.clementine-player.org/) music player and after putting this flac file to play list it loops it. Program won't jump to the next file.

## What Did I try?

I tried putting this file to Audacity in hopes to re-code it but it just filled my entire timeline and crashed my pc (BSOD no more RAM 10GB main + 20GB page file filled). I've also tried searching Google for sollutions.

## So what do I need from the community?

Basically sollution for my problem. Also, MP3 convertion is not an option. I don't like closed-source programs and flac is my favourite lossless and open-source program.

Comment: what is the audio format of your Amiga?Why dont you try converting them in a different lossless format before converting them again to flac?

Comment: I could doing it with WAV and then recoding it to FLAC

Comment: sure. Have you tried?

Comment: converted to wav and recoded it to flac. It works now.

Comment: Cool, but the problems remains unsolved, we still don't know why your first conversion didn't worked out as it should. Can you post the amiga format spec?

Answer (score -2):

Okay. It looks like i just had to convert my mod to wav file and then recode it to flac. Now it works without looping.